# List of tables in Libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice-writer, openoffice-writer

I want index of tables or index of figures that are used in Libreoffice Writer document. How can I have index of charts, tables or formulas as it existed in MS Office word ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the **index type** in the "Indexes and Tables" dialogue: Menu `Insert` -> `Indexes and Tables` -> `Indexes and Tables...`.  Just select the index type from the **`Type` combobox**:

[image: Index of ...]

Depending on the selected entry, the "`Create from`" section in the dialogue will change.

For example, to create an **index of math formulas** in a writer document, you will have to

1. select the "`Table of Objects`" entry in the "`Type`" combobox.
2. Now, you can select "`LibreOffice Math`" Objects from the `Create from` section.

[image: Index of Math Objects (Formulas)]

You can create an **index of charts** the same way (just select `LibreOffice Chart` from the Objects list).

For an **index of tables**, there's a type entry in the Type combobox, too.

### EDIT

For tables and other objects, you can set a **caption** that may appear in the index of tables. There are two ways to insert a own caption:

- Menu `Insert` -> `Caption`
- Context menu of table (right-click) -> `Caption`.

The `Caption` entry **will only be available if the cursor is inside the table** (or, for draw objects: if the object is selected).

To use `Figure` instead of `Table` in the caption, just enter a custom "category" in the `Caption` dialogue:

[image: Caption category]

Take care to set select your caption category when creating the table of tables:

[image: Selecting the caption category]

You could even use the auto-caption feature:

[image: Auto-category button]

[image: Auto-category options]

Comment: How can I mark the tables title as tables or charts. How can set any text as Table,Object or chart? Ms Word offer me a box that I was able to set any text as Title of table or Title of Chart. And it had Figure 21 as prefix .

Comment: @Huseyin: i've emendet my answer, covering custom table captions.